# Is it possible to retrieve deleted tweets or deleted accounts via twitter API?

Tags: twitter, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter4j, twitterapi-python

I wonder is it possible to retrieve deleted tweets or deleted accounts via twitter API?
I know current accounts or tweets can be retrieved but what about the deleted ones?

Answer (score 1):

No. It is completely impossible. If anyone says otherwise it is not true. The Twitter API respects user privacy and you cannot retrieve deleted Tweets.

Comment: Thx Andy for the clarification from a trustworthy source.